# How to update ng-click value in ng-repeat?

Tags: json, dynamic, angularjs

I am writing a form, in that I required dynamic elements which will come from a json script.
here is a sample.

```
<div ng-repeat='element in elements'>
    <input type="button" ng-click="{{element.clickedAction}}" />
</div>
```

But this ng-click is not updating as in json script. How to proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat='element in elements'>
    <input type="button" ng-click="element.clickedAction()" />
</div>
```

Presuming that `clickedAction` is a function on your `element` in the `elements` array.

```js
$scope.elements = [
   { 
      clickedAction: function () { /* do something */ }
   },
   { 
      clickedAction: function () { /* do something */ }
   },
   { 
      clickedAction: function () { /* do something */ }
   }
];
```

This is an unusual scenario though. More often people will be doing something like this:

```js
$scope.doSomething = function(item) {
    item.name += '!';
};

$scope.items = [ { name: 'test' }, { name: 'foo' }, { name: 'bar' } ];
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <button ng-click="doSomething(item)">Click Me</button>
</div>
```